# require and export not working in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have 2 JS files, export.js which exports an array and import.js which implements require() and should use the imported array to print the contents onto the browser in html using a forloop.

It seems from intellisense that the import and export paths are correct but the html produces no output onto the browser. If i use arrays in the import file itself then everything works fine, this array is included in the code posted below but commented out for clarity.
I am confused as to what exactly the problem is this in this case, especially since I tried all the examples found here and through google. I included all the relevant code and files, hopefully somebody can know exactly what is going wrong here.

```
//export.js

var arr = ["example1", "example2", "example3"];
exports.arr = arr;
```

````
 //import.js
var arr = require('../js/exportfile.js').arr;


var arrays = arr
//var arrays = ["example1", "example2", "example3"]; 


for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    document.writeln((i + 1) + ": " + arrays[i]);

document.getElementById("jj").innerHTML += (i + 1) + ": " + arrays[i]; ```
````

```
<div id="jj"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/import.js"></script>
```

Comment: `require()` is a nodejs capability, not something that runs in a browser.   The `document` object only exists in a browser.  So, you are using conflicting technologies in the same script (some that only run in nodejs and some that only run in the browser) and thus your script will not run in either environment.

Comment: @jfriend00  So you mean require() cannot be used to export and import s arrays between 2 javascript files? If I understand you correctly it means require() can only be used within the router such as in files like index and models?

Comment: `require()` does not run in the browser.  That is a technique that works in your server in nodejs, not in the browser.  For regular Javascript files in the browser (not the new ESM modules), you just use multiple `<script>` tags to load each script into the browser and you define functions or variables in the global scope (no import and export).  For ESM modules (the newer kind of modules), you use a different type of script tag to load the top-level module and then you use `import` and `export` from that to load other scripts and to get their exports.

Comment: @jfriend00  Okay I see. Could you perhaps post any links here that show examples of what you saying?

Comment: For ESM modules in the browser, you can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules.